# How to redirect home in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redirect, dropdown, history

I have a login page and I created it with the protected router. Login is successful and I am storing Local Storage. My problem is in Logout. So for this, I have a Navbar component where I have a Logout dropdown. Basically, it is like this:

```
<Dropdown
                nav
                isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
                toggle={(e) => this.dropdownToggle(e)}
              >
                <DropdownToggle caret nav>
                  <i className="now-ui-icons users_circle-08" />
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu right>
                  <DropdownItem tag="logout" onClick={this.signoutHandler}>Logout</DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </Dropdown>
```

So I want to delete localStorage and redirect to thee home page which is Login in this case.

```
signoutHandler = (e) => {
    localStorage.removeItem('user-info');
    e.history.push("/");
  };
```

But it is giving me an error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**
Could you please help me?
Thanks!!!

Comment: You either need to use `window.location.href` or `router.push()`.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting can be done two ways:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Component() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function goHome() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Or

```js
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"

function Component({loggued}){
  if (!logged) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />
  }

  return (
     <>
      hello
     </>
   )
}
```